# v-for loop in vue and to get image next to each other

Tags: vue.js, flexbox

So I have the this array in my js side of vue and the images are getting aligned below each other, I want it to align next to each other, I am using flexbox in scss to display it, but the row is not working, what am I doing wrong?

JS

```
 shop_items:
                [
                    { image_path:"thumb.php?src=./assets/dog.jpg&size=640x480"},
                    { image_path:"thumb.php?src=./assets/cat.jpg&size=640x480"}
                ]
```

HTML

```
 <div class="animal_list" v-for="item in shop_items>
        <img class="image" :src="item.image_path">
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
.animal_list{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Comment: You should make a parent div that contains all of your `animal_list` divs, and move display flex to that parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `v-for` is in wrong place. You are creating a new `div` element for each item of array.

You must create one `div` and many image inside it. See the code below:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="animal_list">
      <template v-for="item in shop_items">
        <img class="image" :src="item.image_path" />
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    shop_items: [
      {
        image_path:
          'https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg',
      },
      {
        image_path:
          'https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg',
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```